# jQuery - How can I from a pop up change a different input values

Tags: jquery, html

How can I change the input value through a pop up.

Let's say I'm building a shopping platform and when the user clicks on the quantity a popup appears. The quantity will be diferent for other products. Here is my code

HTML:

```
    <form action="">
        <input class="qnt" type="text" placeholder="Escolha a quantidade">
        <input class="qnt" type="text" placeholder="Escolha a quantidade">
        <input class="qnt" type="text" placeholder="Escolha a quantidade">
        <input class="qnt" type="text" placeholder="Escolha a quantidade">
    </form>

    <div class="pop_up">
        <div class="pop_up_container">
            <input class="pop_up_campo" type="text">
            <button class="pop_up_confirm">Confirmar!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
var qnt = $('.qnt');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pop_up').hide();
})

qnt.click(function() {
    $('.pop_up').show('fast');
    $('.pop_up_campo').click(function() {
        $('.pop_up_confirm').click(function() {
            $(this).val(qnt.val($('.pop_up_campo').val()));
            $('.pop_up').hide();
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could detect & save the clicked input with `e.target` from the click-event and afterwards write into that saved input

```
var input;
qnt.click(function(e) {
    //Save the selected input
    input = e.target;
    $('.pop_up').show('fast');
});

$('.pop_up_campo').click(function() {
    $('.pop_up_confirm').click(function() {
        //Write into selected input
        $(input).val($('.pop_up_campo').val());
        $('.pop_up').hide();
    })
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvavqyeb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a variable outside your functions to keep track of which input you have selected (and therefore want to change). you dont want to put the button click inside the input click - the input click inside the popup doesnt seem like it should actually trigger any events. so separate the click function that brings up the popup, and the click event that changes the input value while closing the popup

```
var selectedInput = '';
$(document).on('click', '.qnt', function() {
    selectedInput = $(this);
    $('.pop_up').show('fast');
});

$(document).on('click, '.pop_up_confirm', function() {
    selectedInput.val($('.pop_up_campo').val());
    $('.pop_up').hide();
    selectedInput = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for.
[Play with it in Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reYLzB?editors=1111)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //all your jquery code should be wrapped up in document ready
    var id = 1000;  

    //for each .qnt, apply a click listener
    $('.qnt').each(function(){
      var $thisQuantity = $(this);
      $thisQuantity.attr('data-id', id++);
      $thisQuantity.click(function() {
        //copy the .qnt value to pop up input
        $('.pop_up_campo').val($thisQuantity.val());
        $('.pop_up_campo').attr('data-id', $thisQuantity.attr('data-id'));
        $('.pop_up').show('fast');
        $('.pop_up_campo').focus();
      });
    });

    //apply a click handler to your pop_up button
    $('.pop_up_confirm').click(function() {
      var relatedQntId = $('.pop_up_campo').attr('data-id');
      var newValue = $('.pop_up_campo').val();
      $(".qnt[data-id='"+relatedQntId+"']").val(newValue);
      $('.pop_up').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).data("count", 10)` to store data in your clicked element.

See https://api.jquery.com/data/ for more information on how to use the function.